# How to fix list assignment index out of range error even after appending the array

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter, while-loop, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to get user's input through the entry widget into an array, keep note that the user's input is a number. How can I get the users input as an integer.

I tried changing the entry values to int with int(g.get())
but it gives me this line:
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
...
So I tried putting it as a string first with int(str(g.get())
But that gave me the same error line.

Tried it outside the loop to get the values in the array, inside the loop, both, nothing worked.

I'm also not sure if my input into an array algorithm works, I'm thinking I might need to put the widget inside the array(?).

```
    x = 6
    ind = np.arange(N)
    arr = []
    G = tk.Entry(self, textvariable="")
    G.pack
    while x >= 0:
        arr[x] =  int(str(G.get()))
        arr.append(x)
        x = x - 1
```

I expect to have an array of numbers that the user inputted into the entry widget, for example, arr = [6,4,6,3,7]

Comment: If you create an `Entry`, and then *immediately* call `.get()` on it, how are you imagining that you're going to get anything other than an empty string?  When has the user had any chance to enter anything?